# Class validator - validating placeholder properties

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

How can I make class validator work with placeholder property names?

For example:

```js
export class SimpleOperatorValue implements ISimpleOperatorValue {
   @IsNotEmpty()
   [key: string]: TypeValueOperator
}
```

This will not work because "Decorators are not valid here".
How can I work around this?

I tried doing something like this:

```js
export class SimpleOperator implements ISimpleOperator {
   ??? -> what decorators to put here
   value: { [key: string]: TypeValueOperator}
}
```

Instead of:

```js
export class SimpleOperator implements ISimpleOperator {
   @ValidateNested()
   @Type(() => SimpleOperatorValue)
   value: SimpleOperatorValue
}
```

I'd prefer keeping the SimpleOperatorValue class if possible - if not, it's not that important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do in the first snippet, because decorators are runtime objects, they are real functions that act on real fields while your code is executing. But `[key: string]: ...` is a type declaration which exists only at compile-time and is removed after compilation.

Comment: And it's not even clear what `IsNotEmpty` check on arbitrary fields would do, how is it supposed to know which fields exactly must not be empty if it doesn't even know what fields can appear in the object? So it's not clear what the decorator in the second snippet would do. You need to somehow explicitly specify which fields with which names the object has and only then you can tell the validator that those must not be empty. Please think up of a way to do it in your case, and update the post if you have some concrete questions

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be a IsNotEmpty but a ValidateNested on the type. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you mean `@ValidateNested` on `[key: string]: TypeValueOperator`? If so, it's still impossible to do it like in the first snippet, because, again, decorators can only act on specific known fields. In the second snippet you could probably write your custom decorator, that would get all properties that `value` has, and trigger validation for them manually. I don't think there is a nice way to do it unless you provide how exactly you are going to use `SimpleOperation`, maybe the way to go here is to use it as a base class and subclass it adding exact fields or something like that